# What is the name of this plant?

Tags: identification

[image]

I haven’t had luck determining what plant this is. I tried googling by leaf shape, pattern, and color to trying to describe its stem/branch.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be Kalanchoe blossfeldiana, common name Flaming Katy in the US, a houseplant. It needs cutting back, although that would have been better done earlier in the year. It also needs higher light levels - direct sun in summer is a bit much for it, but some morning or afternoon sun is beneficial, especially in winter.

These plants are usually bought in flower, and often disposed off after flowering, because it is quite difficult to get them to flower again. Because its a succulent plant, it's best not to overwater - water when the surface of the soil feels dry to the touch, water well, and empty out any outer tray or pot 30 minutes later. More information here https://www.houseplantsexpert.com/flaming-katy.html